# Python XML - extracting information

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I am very new to Python, and also this is my first time trying to parse XML.
I am interested in information within `str` elements. I can identify that information using the `str@name` attribute value.

```
def get_cg_resources(pref_label, count=10):
    r = request_that_has_the_xml

    ns = {'ns':"http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/"}

    tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(r.text))
    records =[]
    for elem in tree.iter(tag='{http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/}record'):
        record = {
        'title':'',
        'source': '',
        'snippet': '',
        'link':'',
        'image':'',
        'adapter':'CG'
        }
        for value in elem.iter(tag='str'):
            attr = value.attrib['name']
            if(attr == 'dc.title'):
                record['title'] = value.text
            elif(attr == 'authority_name'):
                record['source'] = value.text
            elif(attr == 'dc.description'):
                record['snippet'] = value.text
            elif(attr == 'dc.related.link' ):
                record['link'] = value.text
            elif(attr == 'cached_thumbnail'):
                img_part = value.text
                record['image'] = "http://urlbase%s" % img_part
        records.append(record)

    return  records
```

Is this approach correct/efficient for extracting the information I need? Should I be searching for the `str` elements differently?

Any suggestions for improvements are welcome.

Comment: Is request_that_has_the_xml a global variable? Why isn't it a parameter?

Comment: You can ignore that line, just know that it gives the XML string

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_cg_resources(pref_label, count=10):
    r = request_that_has_the_xml

    ns = {'ns':"http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/"}

    tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(r.text))
```

You dont't need `ElementTree` to extract data from xml, `Element` is enough.

```
    root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
```

If 'str' tag is contained only in 'record' tag you don't have to find 'record'
tag first. You can simply look for 'str' tag. The `iter` method recursively
iterates over it's children.

There is a dict to represent 'namespace'. So you don't have to explicitly list
it's value, 'key:tag', dict is enough.

```
    for elem in root.iter('ns:str',ns):
```

If there are 'str' tags that are contained in other tags that you don't want,
then you have to first find 'record' tags.

```
    records =[]

    for elem in root.iter('ns:record',ns):

         record = {
        'title':'',
        'source': '',
        'snippet': '',
        'link':'',
        'image':'',
        'adapter':'CG'
        }
```

`record` can be initialized as follows,

```
        record =dict.fromkeys(['title','source','snippet','link','image'],'')
        record['adapter']='CG'

        for value in elem.iter('ns:str',ns):
            attr = value.attrib['name']
            if(attr == 'dc.title'):
                record['title'] = value.text
            elif(attr == 'authority_name'):
                record['source'] = value.text
            elif(attr == 'dc.description'):
                record['snippet'] = value.text
            elif(attr == 'dc.related.link' ):
                record['link'] = value.text
            elif(attr == 'cached_thumbnail'):
                img_part = value.text
                record['image'] = "http://urlbase%s" % img_part
        records.append(record)

    return  records
```

The above code means you want to extract value of the 'name' attribute of 'str'
tags which are contained in 'record' tags.

If you want a generator you can simply
replace `records.append(record)` wiht `yield record` and delete `return records`
and `records = []` which will be efficient if the list is huge.